# VirtualBox crashes GNOME when moving window to a different desktop

Tags: gnome, virtualbox, 18.04

When I am using VirtualBox and try to move the window to another desktop it freezes GNOME completely

I am on Ubuntu 18.04

This happens when the process of creating a virtual drive is in progress, when I try to move the VBox window(s) to another desktop on GNOME the DE crashes, the cursor doesn't change it style, it remains the one representing holding something.

GTX 980 - nvidia properitary.

Vbox installed using apt install

Vbox version is: '5.2.10_Ubuntu r121806'

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? How did you install VirtualBox? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: I installed it from repo, using Apt, no errors at all, if i dont move it across desktops in gnome its all OK, but when i am in the process of creating virtual hard drive and then try to move to diffrent desktop it freezes gnome. It should just move to the diffrent desktop, without crashing it.

Comment: From which repository? What's the current VirtualBox version? What's your graphics adapter and which driver does it use?

Comment: GTX 980 - nvidia properitary
i installed it using apt install
Vbox version is: '5.2.10_Ubuntu r121806'

Comment: Alright. Could you please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.